# Wait for all files with a certain extension to stop existing

Tags: linux, shell, while-loop, file-exists

I have a shell script that unzips a bunch of files, then processes the files and then zips them back up again. I want to wait with the processing until all the files are done unzipping.
I know how to do it for one file:

```
while [ -s /homes/ndeklein/mzml/JG-C2-1.mzML.gz ]
do
  echo "test"
  sleep 10
done
```

However, when I do

```
while [ -s /homes/ndeklein/mzml/*.gz ]
```

I get the following error:

```
./test.sh: line 2: [: too many arguments
```

I assume because there are more than 1 results. So how can I do this for multiple files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a subcommand in the shell and check that there is output:

```
while [ -n "$(ls /homes/ndeklein/mzml/*.gz 2> /dev/null)" ]; do
    # your code goes here
    sleep 1; # generally a good idea to sleep at end of while loops in bash
done
```

If the directory could potentially have thousands of files, you may want to consider using `find` instead of `ls` with the wildcard, ie; `find -maxdepth 1 -name "*\.gz"`

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` is your friend if `while` is not coerced.

```
ls /homes/ndeklein/mzml/*.gz | xargs -I {} gunzip {}
```